# How to import settings into CLion afterwards?

Tags: settings, clion

CLion had upgraded itself automatically and asked me to import settiogs from old version which I refused.

Can I import these settings now?

If I am doing `File -> Import Settings` and choosing any of

`/home/MYNAME/.CLion2019.1`

`/home/MYNAME/.CLion2019.1/config`

and so on, it says it can't find `settings.zip`

[image]

If I compress `/home/MYNAME/.CLion2019.1` and try to feed `CLion` with it, it says

[image]

Is it possible to import, or train is gone now?